Is a "condensed" font different in Adobe XD than browsers such as Firefox or Chrome?
I was given a design to follow and in that there were quite a few different fonts and styles. While I managed to pick most of it pretty easily I noticed that the font-stretch isn't exactly the same in the browser as it was on the design.
For example (picked from the XD design):
Font Family: Nunito Sans 10pt Condensed Normal
Font Weight: Condensed
Font Size: 20px
Color: #00000
Character Spacing: 0
Line Spacing: 30
In MDN Web Docs there's an article which says "condensed" is 75%:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-stretch
However, if I put condensed into my font-stretch it isn't the same as in the design. My co-worker found that 84% would be more accurate for that.
Could somebody explain more, why is it so, and if there are any other solutions than "guessing" the font-stretch on each occasion?

Your design app may use static fonts so based on predefined widths (one file per width/weight/style). If you're using variable fonts in a browser changing the font-stretch in small steps it will actually affect the rendered width. if you're using static fonts the browser will try to find the most suitable font . For a consistent result static fonts may be easier to control.

What's the CSS for this comparison?
